# How to replace only whole-word matches in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim

Code sample:

```
for file in files:
  do_something(root+file)
```

I want to replace `file` with `f` but I must keep `files`.

Usually I use the below command:

```
:%s/file/f/gcI
```

but it matches `files` as well. Is there any way to match only a whole word which works for the (root+file) syntax too?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `\<` and `\>` to match the beginning and the end of a word:

```
:%s/\<file\>/f/gcI
```

Comment: `\<` and `\>` is not a vim specific thing. Its a common regex notation to denote full words.

Comment: `\<` and `\>` however do not work in perl-compatible regexes. You can use `\b` instead (word boundary). See `perldoc perlre` because there's also the Unicode boundary, which is `\b{}`.

Answer (score -1):

Does this do it?

%s/\bfile\b/f/gcI

Comment: No it doesn't.  In vim regex `\b` matches the backspace character.

Comment: It would work if vim had perl regexes. Also read: `:help perl-pattern`